# How to add punctuation to data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code for Tacotron 2 where it would get transcripts from youtube & format it in a file. Unfortunately the data it recieves from YT doesn't specify where sentences end. So, I tried adding full stop in the end but most of the sentences isn't a full sentence. So, how can I make it only add full stops at the finish of a sentence. The only other data it recieves are timestamps.

```
# Batch file for Tacotron 2

from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
transcript_txt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript('DY0ekRZKtm4')


def write_transcript():
    with open('transcript.txt', 'a+') as transcript_object:
        transcript_object.seek(0)
        subtitles = transcript_object.read(100)
        if len(subtitles) > 0:
            transcript_object.write('\n')
        for i in transcript_txt:
            ii = i['text']
            if ii[-1] != '.':
                iii = ii + '.'
            else:
                iii = ii
            print(iii)
            transcript_object.write(iii + '\n')
   transcript_object.close()


write_transcript()
```

Here's an example:

```
 What it saves:
    sometimes it was possible to completely.
    fall.
    out of the world if the lag was bad.
    enough.
 What I want:
    sometimes it was possible to completely
    fall
    out of the world if the lag was bad
    enough.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution. The least effort way I can think of is to set up [spaCy](https://spacy.io/), `nlp` the whole transcript and hope for the best. It's not trained on data without punctuation though, so don't expect perfect results, but it will detect *some* sentence boundaries (based on syntax for the most part).

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')

text = """sometimes it was possible to completely
    fall
    out of the world if the lag was bad
    enough
    we solved that by
    adding more test data"""

doc = nlp(text)

for s in doc.sents:
    print(f"'{s}'")
```

##### Output:

```py
'sometimes it was possible to completely
    fall
    out of the world if the lag was bad
    enough
    '
'we solved that by
    adding more test data'
```

So in this case, it worked. Once you have that, you could do some additional processing, add punctuation manually, etc.